# Вычисление в диапазоне

Tags: массивы, c++

Надо найти среднее арифметическое модулей четных элементов в диапазоне (первое отрицательное - последнее положительное).

Как сделать, чтобы считало из диапазона?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void sredArifm(int a[], int, double*, int*, int*, int*);

int main()
{
    double sred;
    int i, n, a[10], posPol, pervOtr, sum;

    cout << "Vvedite razmer massiva: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "\Vvedite massiv:\n";
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Vvedite a[" << i << "]=";
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    cout << "\Massiv a:\n";
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        cout << setw(7) << a[i];
    cout << endl;

    sredArifm(a, n, &sred, &sum, &posPol, &pervOtr);

    cout << "\nPosPol= " << posPol << "\nPervOtr= " << pervOtr << endl;
    cout << "\nsum= " << sum << endl;

    cout << "\nsred=" << sred << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void sredArifm(int a[], int n, double* sred, int*sum, int*posPol, int*pervOtr)
{

    int i, j;
    *pervOtr = a[0];
    *posPol = a[0];
    j = 0, *sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!(a[i] % 2))
        {
            while (a[i] >= 0)
                i++;
                *pervOtr = a[i]; break;
        }
    }
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (!(a[i] % 2))
        {
            if (a[i] > 0)
                *posPol = a[i]; break;
        }
    }
    for (i = *pervOtr; i < *posPol; i++)
    {
        if (!(a[i] % 2))
        {
            *sum += abs(a[i]);
            ++j;
        }
    }
    cout << "\nj=" << j << endl;

     *sred = *sum / j;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала хотелось бы уточнить задание. Первое отрицательное и последнее положительное должны быть четными или любыми?

Теперь про вашу функцию sredArifm:

1. Непонятно, зачем вы в первом цикле сначала ищете четное число, а после, от его позиции, ищете первое отрицательное число. Причем это отрицательное число может быть любым (четным/нечетным). Ход мыслей мне непонятен.
2. Во втором цикле уже правильно. Только условия !(a[i] % 2) и a[i] > 0 можно объединить в одно: !(a[i] % 2) && (a[i] > 0), тем самым уберем лишний if.
3. Следующая ошибка в том, что в третьем цикле, вы используете значения положительного/отрицательного элементов как индексы, что абсурдно. Нужно знать их позиции в массиве, поэтому в первых двух циклах необходимо запомнить не только значения положительного/отрицательного элементов, но и их позиции в массиве.

Если код писали сами, то ошибки быстро исправите.
И еще, небольшая рекомендация: **прекращайте** писать сообщения и имена переменных, функций и т.п. транслитом.